# Angular- use custom Styles parameters like headings "colour" or "border-bottom" colour

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an Angular app, that gets a data from a JSON file via HttpClient, and to update some styles values as color and border. The default color is black and the color value got from JSON "clientName.theme_color" is red, for example. Below is my current code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HeaderUserDetails } from './header-user-details';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  styles: [
    `
        #user-name { color: #000; }
        #company-name nav::after { border-bottom: 5px solid #000; }
    `
    ]
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public clientName = [];
  private _url = 'http://domain.name/JSON/user-details.php';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getUserDetails(): Observable<HeaderUserDetails[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<HeaderUserDetails[]>(this._url)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserDetails()
      .subscribe(data => this.clientName = data);
  }
}
```

How to update the color in @Component "styles" to the NEW one got from the JSON file, that is "clientName.theme_color"? Every user has own theme color. Please see below the JSON structure:

```
{ "id": "001", "name": “John Doe”, "theme_color": "#cc0000" }
```

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/class-binding-ngclass-angular/

Comment: I need to use theming or dynamic CSS variables...